# Permanent visual change via pure CSS/HTML once input button (type=file) is pressed

Tags: html, css

In a web application I maintain, I customized an input button (of type `file`) by making it transparent and positioning it over an `img`. Doing it this way has vast browser compatibility compared to some more sophisticated ways involving `label` and such.

I also wrote simple JS to display the name of the selected file.

Now here's a situation: some users access this app through a forward proxy that strips out JS. In other words, those users don't have access to any JS capabilities.

**The problem:**

My problem is that for such users, the customized input button is unable to display the filename at all. This causes some of them to think the button is broken.

One solution is to detect all these forward proxy users and serve them a different page (one where the input button is unstyled). This task has server-side complications outside the scope of this question.

Hence I'm looking for a pure CSS/HTML solution first. I know I can't use CSS/HTML to show the filename. That's fine.

But is it possible to show any visual change in the customized button once the user has pressed it (e.g. change in `opacity`, `width` or even `positioning` a new div over it)? I'm looking for cross browser compatibility in this solution - **especially mobile web browsers** including Chrome, Android and Opera. Illustrative examples would be great. Also see below to find out what I tried and *almost got to work*.

---

Here's the code I've written to customize the button:

```
<style>

.outer{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:60px;
  max-width:132px
}

img{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:3;
}

input[type=file]{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:4;
  opacity:0;
  max-width:132px;
  height:60px
}

</style>

<div class="outer">
    <img src="cam.svg" width="60" height="60">
    <input type="file"> 
</div>
```

---

Here's one thing I tried that actually works (but **isn't cross browser**):

```
   <style>

    #input:target + span:after{
        content:"File Selected";
        position: absolute;
        z-index:5;
    }

    .outer{
      position:relative;
      overflow:hidden;
      height:60px;
      max-width:132px
    }

    img{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:3;
    }

    input[type=file]{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:4;
      opacity:0;
      max-width:132px;
      height:60px
    }

    </style>


    <div class="outer">
         <img src="cam.svg" width="60" height="60">
         <a href="#input"><input id="input" type="file"><span></span></a> 
    </div>
```

Ergo, I called file input via `<a href="#input">`, and then styled the empty `span` occurring right after the `target`. This patterns breaks down in some older browsers I must entertain. Maybe I should have used a basic `label`?

Any innovative solutions that solve my problem are most welcome. I'm okay with hacky stuff, as long as it's cross-browser compatible.

Comment: You want a certain text to appear on the the image yet the  image must be clickable still,  right ?